# admob interstial logic and acceptable refresh time

Tags: request, refresh, admob, ads

In AdMob interstitial ads, the refresh times do not exist. My application uses one activity with one button in the activity. When users click, this code is ran:

```
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My application works fine and it was published in Google Play. When the users click on the button they get the interstitial ad. For example the user can click (6 clicks in one minute) so the time between two clicks is 10 seconds. My question is, is this logic and acceptable by AdMob? I am worried that AdMob will ban me. So what is the minimal time acceptable between two ad requests?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if AdMob sees a repeated pattern they may invalidate the impressions and clicks.

I suggest you do a bit of research first and contact AdMob at support@admob.com.

- [AdMob Guidelines and Policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en)
- [AdMob Terms of Service](http://www.admob.com/home/terms)